# When back from activity to the parent layout drawer menu hover wrong menu

Tags: android-layout, navigation-drawer, back-button

I have a problem when opening activity from the navigation menu and when the back button clicks, it come back into the parent layout but the navigation menu hover (Current Menu Fragment/Activity Pointer) shows the menu that is connected to the previous activity.

### it's obvious in the images below:

[image]

#### if the gif is not obvious main quality of it is below link.

[Gif With Main Quality](https://i.imgur.com/oIsokFj.mp4)

> when back from the activity (in the gif it's 'Custom') into the parent fragment ( 'Home') the ('Custom') menu is hover, but it should hover the ('Home').

When We Back From Activity Drawer Should Hover The 'Home' Like Below But it Hovers The 'Custom'
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle it through code, using `setChecked(boolean checked)` method

Comment: where should i add this method?

Comment: on `public void onBackPressed()` you can set checked false to the selected navigation item, in your MainActivity